# set focus after replaceWith

Tags: jquery, focus, invoice

I'm working on an invoice system and I've come to the part of line items.

For this, I have a table, that will eventually have a button to add another line item dynamically to the DOM.

Until that point, I am trying to work the kinks out of a single line item.  In my case, it is the notes section.

For the input of notes, I have a P tag with some text and onclick of that element replaces it with a textarea.

```
<h2>line items</h2><hr>
    <table id='lineitems'>
        <tr>
            <th>Order #</th>
            <th>Style #</th>
            <th>Item Name/Description</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' name='ladingnum' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='invoicenum' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='invoicenum' style='width:300px;'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='invoicenum' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='invoicenum' /></td>    
        </tr><tr><td colspan=4>
            <div id='thenotes'>
                <input type='hidden' class='comments' name='notes'/>
                <textarea class='comments'></textarea>
                <p class='edit'>[ click here to add notes ]</p>
            </div>
        </td></tr>

    </table>
```

This is the jQuery I am using.

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
    var odata = $(this).closest("input:hidden").val();
    if( odata == undefined ) odata = '';
    $(this).closest("textarea.comments").val(odata).focus();
});

$(document).on('focusout', '.liveedit', function () {
        var idata = $(this).val();
        if( idata == '' ) idata = "[ click here to add notes ]";
        $(this).prevAll("input:hidden").val(idata);
        $(this).replaceWith("<p class='edit'>"+idata+"</p>");
});
```

Using that, I get this effect.

Page loads... the P tag has default content of click here to add notes.  On click it turns into a textarea that contains whatever is in the hidden field.  It is also supposed to focus on this newly created textarea....it is not focusing!

On top of that. I can't seem to get the value of the textarea to go into the hidden input field... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector `.closest('input:hidden')` will only select it's closest parent, not siblings. You have to use `.siblings('input:hidden')` or `.closest('div').find('input:hidden')` to select the input and textarea.

Something like this:

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NcV7v/)**

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.edit', function () {
        var odata = $(this).closest("div").find("input:hidden").val();
        if (odata == undefined) odata = '';
        $(this).closest("div").find("textarea.comments").val(odata).focus();
    });

    $(document).on('focusout', '.liveedit', function () {
        var idata = $(this).val();
        if (idata == '') idata = "[ click here to add notes ]";
        $(this).prevAll("input:hidden").val(idata);
        $(this).replaceWith("<p class='edit'>" + idata + "</p>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `siblings` instead of `closest`.Try this:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
var odata = $(this).siblings("input[type='hidden']").val();
if( odata == undefined ) odata = '';
$(this).siblings("textarea.comments").val(odata).focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The hidden `<input>` and the `<p>` tag are siblings so you should the `siblings()` selector instead. `closest()` is used to traverse through the ancestor of the element until it finds the match selector. You are also not creating any `<textarea>` on your code but I suppose that's what `'.liveedit'` is for:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function () {
    var odata = $(this).siblings("input:hidden").val();
    if (odata == undefined) odata = '';
    var textarea = $('<textarea class="liveedit">' + odata + '</textarea>');
    $(this).replaceWith(textarea);
    textarea.focus();
});

$(document).on('focusout', '.liveedit', function () {
    var idata = $(this).val();
    if (idata == '') idata = "[ click here to add notes ]";
    $(this).siblings("input:hidden").val(idata);
    $(this).replaceWith("<p class='edit'>" + idata + "</p>");
});
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yKym7/1/